# Update class which has another class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have a product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to update the model doing this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Product product) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        product.Brand = db.Brands.Find(product.Brand.Id);

        db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(product);
}
```

The problem is that all my properties are updated but Brand !!
How can I do to update it?

---

If I do:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Product product) 
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)  
     {
          db.Products.Attach(product);

          product.Brand = db
              .Brands
              .Find(2); // << with a static value

          db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

          db.SaveChanges();

          return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
      return View(product);
 }
```

it works... but if I try this below, even though the BrandId is 2, it doesn't work:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Product product) 
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)  
        {
            db.Products.Attach(product);

            int BrandId = product.Brand.Id;

            product.Brand = db
                .Brands
                .Find(BrandId);

            db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(product);
    }
```

Comment: Your code does not set a different Brand. You select the Brand that Product already has.

Comment: In the view, brand is a dropdown, so product parameter has the brand id=1 but all other properties are null.. even if I do 'db.Entry(product.Brand).State = EntityState.Modified;', it doesn't work.

Comment: You probably need to attach the Product to the context.

Comment: I just tried, doesn't work too.

Comment: If I set brand manually(product.Brand = db.Brands.find(x)), so that's work !!

Comment: Can you show what `Brand` looks like? Is this a one-to-one relationship or a one-to-many?

Comment: It's a one to one.     public class Brand
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must handle updating the relationship between `Product` and `Brand` separately. The relationship is not affected by setting the state manually to `Modified`. It is especially important to load the `Brand` (together with the product) from the DB first, otherwise EF cannot detect if the relationship changed or not:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Product product) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        var productInDB = db.Products.Include(p => p.Brand)
            .Single(p => p.Id == product.Id);

        // Update scalar properties
        db.Entry(productInDB).CurrentValues.SetValues(product);

        // Update relationship between product and brand
        if (product.Brand == null && productInDB.Brand != null)
            productInDB.Brand = null;
        else if (product.Brand != null && (productInDB.Brand == null
            || product.Brand.Id != productInDB.Brand.Id))
        {
            db.Brands.Attach(product.Brand);
            productInDB.Brand = product.Brand;
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(product);
}
```

This procedure becomes much easier if you introduce a foreign key property `BrandId` in your `Product` entity and set this `product.BrandId` in the view instead of `product.Brand.Id`. In this case setting the state to `Modified` would work because `BrandId` is a scalar property.